# How to share desktop PC internet connection with a connected windows 10 tablet via USB

Tags: network-shares, windows-10, usb, connection-sharing

I am trying to find the right way to share my w10 pro desktop internet connection with my w10 pro tablet via a `USB 3.0` port. The tablet-netbook is an [ASUS Transformer Book](https://www.asus.com/us/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T100TA/).

I do not want to use ethernet-to-usb adapter or something similar nor a wifi hotspot. In addition, I would like to avoid using any kind of "special equipment". The question is whether its doable as it is on windows 10 and how to do it.

I couldnt find anything relevant on google, search results were mostly related with android connection tethering which is not what I want to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [feng shui](https://www.karenkingston.com/blog/how-to-shield-your-home-from-neighbourhood-wifi/) home ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 No, just no wifi at all and no ethernet on tablet.

Comment: I'am surprised no wifi on the tablet, but check that article; https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9-0pvnvlicYJ:https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/connecting-two-pcs-using-a-usb-usb-cable/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca First page is 404, thus google cached, but other page seem to work

Comment: Please edit the question with the make/model of the tablet.  Do you have the USB cable to connect your Win10 PC to the tablet?  I've heard of this being doable with USBA-USBA cables, but perhaps you can do the same thing with what you have.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Just added the model. For now I use the micro USB 2.0 but the netbook supports usb 3.0 and type-C.

Answer (score 0):

That article there seem to cover your need;

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9-0pvnvlicYJ:https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/connecting-two-pcs-using-a-usb-usb-cable/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca

First page is google cached, but other pages seem to work.

> A very easy way to connect two PCs is to use a USB-USB cable. By
>   connecting two PCs with a cable like this, you can transfer files from
>   one PC to another, and even build a small network and share your
>   Internet connection with a second PC. In this tutorial, we will
>   explain you how to connect two PCs using this type of cable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the article seems to be too old. Also I would like to avoid purchasing any kind of `special` equipment.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible without specialized emulation software that I can't find anywhere. Also unless both USB ports are 3.0 you'll have to get a special USB bridge cable anyways. https://superuser.com/questions/795053/how-do-i-connect-two-computers-using-usb-3-0

Microsoft never openly supported a feature like this and their Windows Mobile devices never supported reverse tethering either even though it was popular on Android phones (as you found). If your laptop has an internal wifi card you can create an [ad hoc network](https://www.howto-connect.com/create-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-on-windows-10/), unless you don't have any wifi capability at all

Comment: @LostWarder The usb is indeed usb 3.0